# git pull --rebase resolve conflicts by keeping local changes

Tags: git, rebase, pull

I rebased to master on my local branch. Meanwhile someone did changes on this branch on remote. I am doing `git pull --rebase`. I don't understand how git interprets this command when it comes to the naming of `current` and `incoming`, as well as `ours` and `theirs`.

Which should I choose to always keep my local changes? Also, after my first rebase with master, there are dozens of conflicts. Is there a command to make `git pull --rebase` just keep all my local changes, instead of having to do it manually? I know about `ours` and `theirs`, but I don't know how to incorporate those keywords in `git pull --rebase` command.

This stuff is confusing as hell, since all those keywords get reversed between merge and rebase, and then there is pull with rebase to add extra confusion.

Comment: For `git pull --rebase`, to keep "my" changes, use `git pull --rebase -Xtheirs`. For `git pull` without `--rebase`, to keep "my" changes, use `git pull -Xours`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The command to favor the changes in *your local branch* is:

```
git pull --rebase -X theirs
```

The reason why you have to say "theirs" when, intuitively, you'd like to say "ours" is because the meaning of "ours" and "theirs" is swapped during a rebase compared to a merge. Let me explain.

#### Ours and Theirs in a Merge vs. Rebase

When you do a merge, you're always merging into the current branch; in case of a conflict, "ours" means *the branch you're on*, while "theirs" means *the branch you're merging*. Exactly as you would expect.

A rebase is different. Let's say that you're rebasing a branch called `local` onto `master`.

```
        master
        ⌄
o---o---o
    \
     A---B---C ‹ local
```

During a rebase, Git creates a sort of "temporary branch" to do the work<sup>1</sup>. It starts by moving `HEAD` to the tip of the branch you're rebasing onto, in this case `master`:

```
        master
        ⌄   
o---o---o ‹ HEAD
    \
     A---B---C ‹ local
```

Then, it cherry-picks the commits from `local` one at a time:

```
        master
        ⌄   
o---o---o---A'---B' ‹ HEAD
    \
     A---B---C ‹ local
```

Now, let's image that commit `C` has a conflict:

```
        master
        ⌄             X
o---o---o---A'---B'---C' ‹ HEAD
    \
     A---B---C ‹ local
```

In this case, "ours" indicates the temporary branch Git is working on, while "theirs" is the branch from which the commit was cherry-picked, which is `local`.

If you wanted to keep the changes in your `local` branch, you'd have to choose the "theirs" side. If, instead, you wanted to keep the changes in `master`, you'd choose the "ours" side.

Once the conflict has been resolved, Git completes the rebase operation by moving `local` to point to where `HEAD` is:

```
        master
        ⌄             
o---o---o---A'---B'---C' ‹ HEAD, local
    \
     A---B---C
```

Given that no branch is left referencing commit `C`, those commits become [*unreachable*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefunreachableobjectaunreachableobject) and will eventually be deleted:

```
        master
        ⌄             
o---o---o---A'---B'---C' ‹ HEAD, local
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It's really just a [*detached head*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head), but for the purpose of this explanation, you can think of it as a temporary branch, even though no branch reference is being created.