# When I `git pull --rebase` and get a conflict, how do I `git show` the other person's commit?

Tags: git, merge, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

So I do `git pull --rebase`, and there's a conflict. Ok, fine, let's resolve it.

I run `git diff` and the merge conflict diff is a bit confusing. I think I need to `git show` the two commits that are being merged, and see how they each independently attempted to modify the same piece of code.

So I run `git status` to see where we are and I get something like this:

```
$ git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto abc123
Last command done (1 command done):
   pick def456 Make some changes blah blah blah
No commands remaining.
You are currently rebasing branch 'main' on 'abc123'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

[file listing goes here]
```

The above mentions two commits:

- `abc123`: I *think* this is the HEAD of the remote branch that I'm pulling into mine. So this is what I ultimately want to rebase onto, but I'm not up to this commit yet, so this doesn't help me.
- `def456`: this is my commit, which is conflict with... something else.

What's *not* listed there is the other half of the current merge conflict. I know that my commit is `def456`, but it doesn't tell me anything about the commit made by someone else, which my commit is in conflict with. This is very frustrating as I can't `git show blah` in order to see what the other author changed in isolation in order to understand the semantics of their change and then merge it with mine.

Currently I go and log into the web UI (e.g. github), look at the list of recent commits, and find the first one after the already-merged `abc123`, but there must be an easy way to get this from the CLI.

Is there?

Comment: Commits plain and simple do not conflict; that's not how merge works. And you don't resolve a conflict by looking at commits. Let's concentrate on the actual conflict.  What is the name of the conflicted file? Is this an edit conflict? Why can't you just look at the file to see the conflict info? Show more of what Git is telling you please.

Comment: During a merge conflict, `git show :2:filename` is one version of the file and `git show :3:filename` is the other version of the file. Is that what you want to know?

Answer (score 3):

As [Enrico Campidoglio noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69256017/1256452), it's tricky to find the *original* source of your conflict.  I think it's worth expanding on *why*, though.  [matt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69254010/when-i-git-pull-rebase-and-get-a-conflict-how-do-i-git-show-the-other-per#comment122407010_69254010) mentioning the `:2` and `:3` syntax, for looking at the copies of files in Git's index, is fine and correct as far as it goes, but that may not be far enough:

> ```
> Last command done (1 command done):
>   pick def456 Make some changes blah blah blah
> ```
>
> ...
> `def456`: this is my commit, which is conflict with... something else

The *something else* is the commit Git is building on, which—depending on what's in the rebase—is quite often one of your own commits that's been copied so far.  So the files here *can* be useful: that's where the *immediate* conflict is coming from.  That might be enough.  But where did the *original* conflict come from?

#### Rebase, part 1

Let's look at a typical rebase operation and give each commit a simple one-letter fake-hash-ID-name so that they're easy to talk about.  We start with:

```
...--E--F   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          G--H--I   <-- my-new-feature (HEAD)
```

or—if you haven't been giving yourself good branch names to try to keep yourself-today from confusing yourself-tomorrow—perhaps:

```
...--E--F   <-- origin/main
         \
          G--H--I   <-- main (HEAD)
```

That is, you made three commits of your own, `G`, `H`, and `I`.  These three commits extend out from the tip of a sequence of commits that was and/or still is found by some branch name in your repository: commit `F` specifically, which might be found only by a *remote-tracking name* like `origin/main`, or might be found by your branch name `main` if you were working in a branch named `my-new-feature`.

You ran `git fetch` and `git rebase`.  You may have done this by entering `git pull` on the command line, which runs `git fetch` and then a second command, in which case, you told it to run rebase as its second command.  Either way the `git fetch` obtained some new commits; I'll draw in two here, and update `origin/main` to point to the last of these two:

```
          J--K   <-- origin/main
         /
...--E--F
         \
          G--H--I   <-- my-new-feature (HEAD)
```

I stopped drawing in the name `main` at all, since we don't need it; if you were (and still are) calling your new branch `main`, that's the name that finds commit `I`, but either way we have one name that finds commit `I` and one that finds commit `K`, and those are the two names of interest.

Now we execute the *second* command that `git pull` would run, i.e., `git rebase`.  The rebase command works by *copying* some existing commits, that are OK but not quite up to snuff for some reason, to new-and-improved commits.  The improvement may involve:

- changing the "base" commit (hence the name `rebase`); and/or
- changing the *stored snapshot* in some way.

While the stored snapshot is the reason for Git's existence, it's the *changes between pairs of stored snapshots* that humans tend to care about.  The rebase operation produces the new and improved commits such that the changes-between-pairs match the original changes-between-pairs:

- (`F`, `G`) is a pair of commits on *your* branch, with some changes.
- (`G`, `H`) is a pair of commits on *your* branch, with some changes.
- (`H`, `I`) is a pair of commits on *your* branch, with some changes.

Git doesn't need to list the pairs directly: it just lists the *second* commit's hash ID.  The first commit in each pair is automatically just the *parent commit* of that second commit, because these pairs are (necessarily) parent-child pairs.

So `git rebase` lists out the hash IDs of the three commits to copy: `G`, `H`, and `I`.  Then `git rebase`:

1. enters *detached HEAD* mode:

   ```
             J--K   <-- origin/main, HEAD
            /
   ...--E--F
            \
             G--H--I   <-- my-new-feature
   ```
2. starts running `git cherry-pick`, one cherry (one commit) at a time:

   ```
   git cherry-pick <hash-of-G>
   git cherry-pick <hash-of-H>
   git cherry-pick <hash-of-I>
   ```

Each of these cherry-pick operations *is* a merge, of sorts.  So each one can fail with a merge conflict.  The only one with a *clear* merge conflict, though, is the *first* one.  Let's explore why.

#### Cherry-pick vs merge

With a standard `git merge`, we start with two branches that share some commit in the past:

```
          o--o--o--L   <-- my-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--o--B
         \
          o--o--o--R   <-- their-branch
```

We're on branch `my-branch`, as indicated by `HEAD` being attached to `my-branch`.  Commit `L` (the left-side or local or `--ours` commit) is the *current commit*, and it has some snapshot.  The other `--theirs` commit, on the right side or *remote*, is commit `R`.  The common starting point—the *merge base*—is commit `B`.  Commits `B` and `R` also have some snapshot each.

Git will diff (as in `git diff --find-renames`) commits `B` and `L` to figure out *what we changed:* which files did we touch?  What lines did we add and/or remove?  Git will then diff `B` and `R`, to get the same kind of information about what *they* changed: which files did they touch and what lines did they add or remove?

Git can now *combine* these changes.  When we touched a file and they didn't, that's easy: take our change.  When they touched a file and we didn,t' that's easy too: take their change.  When we both touched the *same* file, that's harder, but Git can combine these changes, and can tell whether we touched the *same lines* of the file, because we both started from the *same file* in `B`, so if we touched line 17 of that file in `B`, and they only touched line 42, those changes don't collide with each other.

(Git is very line oriented here.  Changes are on a line-by-line basis only, and are combined that way.  This does not have to be how a merge engine works, but it *is* how *Git's* engines work.  Technically, Git has a pluggable merge architecture, but of all of the merge engines that you can plug in, all work this way.)

If we have a conflict, we can easily see exactly where it comes from.  The merge base version of the file is in index slot 1, so `git show :1:file.ext` shows us that version of the file.  Our version of the file is in index slot 2 (and also in the commit found by the name `HEAD`), so `git show :2:file.ext` or `git show HEAD:file.ext` shows us *that* version of the file.  Their version of the file is in index slot 3 (and also in the commit found by the temporary name `MERGE_HEAD`), so `git show :3:file.ext` or `git show MERGE_HEAD:file.ext` shows us their version of the file.<sup>1</sup>

Once the merge is all done, Git makes a merge commit—or has us make one, if we have to solve the conflicts first—and the new merge commit itself also has a (single) snapshot of all files.  This is, by definition, the correct result of the merge.  Where there were conflicts, Git made *us* solve them, and so our solutions are the correct ones.  We can draw in our merge like this:

```
          o--o--o--L
         /          \
...--o--B            M   <-- my-branch (HEAD)
         \          /
          o--o--o--R   <-- their-branch
```

The *only* thing special about new merge commit `M` is that instead of just one parent, it has two: the *first* parent is `L`, the commit that was ours a moment ago, and the *second* parent is `R`.  The diff from `L` to `M` is the resolved result of merging `R`, and the diff from `R` to `M` is the resolved result of merging `L`.  The resolution here is inherent in the snapshot in commit `M`.

When we run `git cherry-pick`, though, the picture is different:

```
          o--...--P--C--...
         /
...--o--o--...--L   <-- my-branch (HEAD)
```

We run `git cherry-pick C` to copy the *changes* in commit `C`, the one we want copied.  But *what are the **changes** in commit `C`?*  Commits hold *snapshots*, not *changes*.

To find changes, Git has to find the parent `P` of child commit `C`.  Git can then run a `git diff` on `P` vs `C`, to find changes.  Git should include `--find-renames` too, in case commit `C` renamed a file.  Git now has to *combine* those changes with ... what?  Commit `L`, like `C`, just holds a *snapshot*.

Git *could* **try** to apply those changes as a `git diff`, and early versions of Git did just that.  In fact, up until recently, the standard `git rebase` ran `git format-patch` to turn commits into patches suitable for emailing, then ran `git am` on the resulting email files to apply them.  This was the `git-rebase--am` *back end* for `git rebase`, which still exists and can still be used today.  It has some flaws: for instance, it *doesn't* detect renames, and it cannot copy an empty-change-set commit.<sup>2</sup>  So it is, as of Git 2.26, no longer the default for rebase.  In any case, it has not been used in `git cherry-pick` for a very long time.

In any case, what cherry-pick does to detect conflicts reliably is to treat commit `P` as the *merge base* for merging purposes.  That is, the cherry-pick code runs a merge with `P` as a faked-up merge base.  Commit `L`, the local or `--ours` commit, is `--ours` as always, so for any changes Git finds between a file as it exists in `P` and as it exists in `L`, Git will keep our "changes", i.e., keep the file the way it looks in `L`.  Git will then *add* to those "changes" (that get us our `L` copy) any changes in the `P`-vs-`C` diff.

So, when we run `git cherry-pick C`—for any reason—the three commits involved are commit `C` itself of course as `--theirs`, `C`'s parent `P` as the merge base, and our own current commit as `--ours` as usual.  If we get conflicts, we presumably know all about *our* file—it's just our file after all—and we can look at `P` and `C` and the changes between them to see what they changed and why.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's some annoying squirrelliness (squirrelly-ness? the built in spelling check does not like even plain [squirrelly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squirrelly), though is in fact a word) around renames here.  The file named `file.ext` might have a *different name* in one or two or even all three commits, yet still be *the same file*.

<sup>2</sup>The `git am` or `git apply` back-end could theoretically *miss* a conflict in some cases where `git rebase` could theoretically detect one.  Whether this theoretical miss ever has any practical difference, I'm not sure.  Because Git is pretty consistent inside its diff and merge engines, I'm not sure there is a way to trigger this.  When `git am` or `git apply` does detect a conflict and does the "falling back" to 3-way merge trick, the result ends up being the same as when using cherry-pick.  Besides this, `git apply` was recently taught to notice the `index` lines and use the 3-way merge earlier, so this may erase any theoretical difference as well.  This, however, will depend on your specific Git version, since Git versions predating, say, 2.20 don't use `index` lines aggressively.

---

#### Rebase, part 2

All that stuff about how to handle the cherry-pick operation is fine when *we're* the ones running `git cherry-pick`, but during `git rebase`, *Git* is the one running cherry-pick, over and over again:

```
          J--K   <-- origin/main, HEAD
         /
...--E--F
         \
          G--H--I   <-- my-new-feature
```

Git runs `git cherry-pick hash-of-G` to copy commit `G` to a new and improved commit, which we'll call `G'`.

Knowing how cherry-pick works, and that `G` is *our* first commit on our new feature, we can just look at files from commit `K` when there's a conflict: that's *their* file.  We know that "their" change—parent-vs-child—is really *our* change in commit `G`.  We can use this knowledge to solve any conflicts, and allow Git to make the new copy `G'`:

```
               G'  <-- HEAD
              /
          J--K   <-- origin/main
         /
...--E--F
         \
          G--H--I   <-- my-new-feature
```

But now, Git runs `git cherry-pick hash-of-H` to copy commit `H` to a new and improved commit, which we'll call `H'`.  The result will—if all goes well—look like this:

```
               G'-H'  <-- HEAD
              /
          J--K   <-- origin/main
         /
...--E--F
         \
          G--H--I   <-- my-new-feature
```

At this point Git will run `git cherry-pick hash-of-I` to copy commit `I` to a new and improved `I'`.  If this has a *conflict*, we're still in the state we drew above.  The `--ours` commit is commit `H'`: our copy of `H`.  The `--theirs` commit is commit `I`: our change from `H` to `I`.  The conflict is in some file in the `--ours` commit, `H'`, vs some file in the `--theirs` commit, `I`, as compared to some file in commit `H`. **All three commits are ours!**

The problem here is that the *conflicting part* in our commit `H'`, as diffed against merge base commit `H`, actually came from commit `J` or `K`.  **This is the key realization.  Without it, Enrico Campidoglio's answer doesn't make sense.  Once we *do* realize it, the answer suddenly makes sense.**  If some line in `H`-vs-`H'` conflicts with our own `H`-vs-`I` change, we must find the right line(s) in commits `J` and/or `K`, to understand why they made their change.

One problem with just using the line numbers from `H'` is that they may not match the line numbers in `J` and/or `K`.  What we really need is the line numbers as they existed—and still exist—in `J` and/or `K` *before* Git imported our commits `G` and `H`.

We want to look at commits in the `--onto` target—here, `origin/main` or commit `K`—that are not in the original source branch: here, that's commit `F`, which may not have a name.  Git's *reflogs* can be helpful, as `origin/main@{1}` will contain the hash ID of commit `F`.  Or, if we are using our own branch name, and have a branch name `main` around, pointing to commit `F`, we can use that.  Running:

```
git log origin/main@{1}..origin/main
```

or:

```
git log main..origin/main
```

will show us the log messages for `J` and `K`; adding `-p` will show those as patches, though because `git log` is unhelpful with merge commits we might want `git log -m -p` or `git log --cc -p` if there are potential merge commits in that range.

Once we do resolve the conflict and continue, rebase will finish with the last copy, and then yank the branch name over:

```
               G'-H'-I'  <-- my-new-feature (HEAD)
              /
          J--K   <-- origin/main
         /
...--E--F
         \
          G--H--I   ???
```

All of our conflict resolutions are now recorded in our three copies, just as when we did a merge and recorded the conflict resolution in the snapshot in merge commit `M`.

#### Conclusion

**There is no perfect answer here.**  The conflicts are often in commits that are all, in some sense, "our" commits.  They are occurring *because of* commits that come *before* these commits, in which case we might find them in those earlier commits; but if we had to resolve some conflicts during one of our earlier cherry-picks, they may even be [*sui generis*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/sui-generis), arising from our own earlier resolution.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] it doesn't tell me anything about the commit made by someone else, which my commit is in conflict with.

While this is [trivial to do during a merge operation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_merge_log), thanks to the [`--merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---merge) option of [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt):

> `--merge`
> After a failed merge, show refs that touch files having a conflict and don’t exist on all heads to merge.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work during a rebase due to the lack of `MERGE_HEAD` (a reference to the commit being merged into the one referenced by `HEAD`).

The good news is that you can work around this limitation by manually looking for commits that touch the conflicting lines. It's just a bit more involved.

First off, get the paths of the [conflicting files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203):

```sh
# 'U' means unmerged
git diff --diff-filter=U --name-only
```

Then, identify the range of lines from the "*other side*" of the conflict. Since this is a rebase operation, ["*ours*" is actually "*theirs*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63612379/26396), so you'll be looking at the `HEAD` section:

```
1 │ <<<<<<< HEAD
2 │ Here's some content
3 │ =======
4 │ Here's some different content
5 │ >>>>>>> def456 (Your commit)
```

With these two pieces of information, you can now get a list of commits that touched the conflicting lines starting from the commit you're rebasing onto (in your example, `abc123`) using the [`-L`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Lltstartgtltendgtltfilegt) option of [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt):

```
git log --oneline -L1,2:path/to/conflicting/file abc123
```

Note that you'll have to take into account the *conflict markers* when identifying the range of lines that contain the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario you probably don't care about what changed on the target branch from a specific commit standpoint. Instead, what matters is the changes (per file) on the target branch since your branch diverged. So the diff you're asking about ("how they each independently attempted to modify the same piece of code") is between the `merge-base` of your branch and the target branch, and the tip of the target branch which you are rebasing onto. For example, if you have branch `abc123` checked out and rebase it onto `main`, you would want to find the merge-base of these 2 branches:

```
git merge-base main abc123
```

and then compare that commit with `main` to see the total changes between those 2 commits. You can drill down to a per file basis to see the exact changes that happened on the target branch when determining how to resolve conflicts with your *current* commit during the rebase. (Note the order of branches doesn't matter with the merge-base command, in case you're rebasing the other way.)

**Tip:** If I'm planning to eventually squash my branch into fewer commits, I usually find it better to do so before I perform a branch rebase onto the target branch. This way I'll have fewer total commits that can possibly conflict when I do rebase onto the target. (Otherwise you sometimes have to step through multiple conflicts and the rebase takes longer.)

**Side note**: Your question contains this text:

> rebasing branch 'main' on 'abc123'.

which *feels* backwards to me because typically you don't rewrite commits on branches such as `main`. Not sure if that was intentional or not.

Answer (score 1):

To extend [Enrico Campidoglio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26396/enrico-campidoglio)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69256017/6309) avout "doesn't tell me anything about the commit made by someone else, which my commit is in conflict with." and [`git log --merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---merge):

With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e09f1254c54329773904fe25d7c545a1fb4fa920), "[`git log --merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a887bdd9276acbcf359d86cc121fc4161293d13/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L343)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---merge))</sup> learned to pay attention to `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` and other kinds of `*_HEAD` pseudorefs.

See [commit f3fc5d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3fc5d9c912df0e07c43a79f289220434f72b617), [commit f476143](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f476143ee6c8a58f41c569e4a637bc441b1e6f4a) (28 Feb 2024) by [Michael Lohmann (`miallo`)](https://github.com/miallo).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6a887bd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a887bdd9276acbcf359d86cc121fc4161293d13), 07 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`revision`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3fc5d9c912df0e07c43a79f289220434f72b617): implement `git log --merge` also for `rebase`/`cherry-pick`/`revert`
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Johannes Sixt</sup>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Michael Lohmann</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> '[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f3fc5d9c912df0e07c43a79f289220434f72b617/Documentation/git-log.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> learned in [ae3e5e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae3e5e1ef2271524882d6bb7c0469f777a255315) ("[`git log -p --merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ae3e5e1ef2271524882d6bb7c0469f777a255315/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L16)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--p))</sup> [[--] paths...]", 2006-07-03, Git v1.4.2-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/868227b0d1f3a295ea9afe7a3be3a1fbdff62442)) to show commits touching conflicted files in the range `HEAD...MERGE_HEAD`, an addition documented in [d249b45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d249b455475977f305240bb73473f25d040012cf) ("Document rev-list's option `--merge`", 2006-08-04, Git v1.4.2-rc4 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d249b455475977f305240bb73473f25d040012cf)).
>
> It can be useful to look at the commit history to understand what lead to merge conflicts also for other mergy operations besides merges, like cherry-pick, revert and rebase.
>
> For rebases and cherry-picks, an interesting range to look at is `HEAD...{REBASE_HEAD,CHERRY_PICK_HEAD}`, since even if all the commits included in that range are not directly part of the 3-way merge, conflicts encountered during these operations can indeed be caused by changes introduced in preceding commits on both sides of the history.
>
> For revert, as we are (most likely) reversing changes from a previous commit, an appropriate range is `REVERT_HEAD..HEAD`, which is equivalent to `REVERT_HEAD...HEAD` and to `HEAD...REVERT_HEAD`, if we keep `HEAD` and its parents on the left side of the range.
>
> As such, adjust the code in `prepare_show_merge` so it constructs the range `HEAD...$OTHER` for `OTHER={MERGE_HEAD, CHERRY_PICK_HEAD, REVERT_HEAD or REBASE_HEAD}`.
> Note that we try these pseudorefs in order, so keep `REBASE_HEAD` last since the three other operations can be performed during a rebase.
> Note also that in the uncommon case where `$OTHER` and `HEAD` do not share a common ancestor, this will show the complete histories of both sides since their root commits, which is the same behaviour as currently happens in that case for `HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD`.
>
> [jc: tweaked in j6t's precedence fix that tries `REBASE_HEAD` last]

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f3fc5d9c912df0e07c43a79f289220434f72b617/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L344-L348):

> Show commits touching conflicted paths in the range `HEAD...<other>`,
> where `<other>` is the first existing pseudoref in `MERGE_HEAD`,
> `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, `REVERT_HEAD` or `REBASE_HEAD`.
>
> Only works
> when the index has unmerged entries.
> This option can be used to show relevant commits when resolving conflicts from a 3-way merge.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I `git show` the other person's commit?

What you are asking for is either easy or maybe possible depending slightly on what you mean.

To start with the easy interpretation, when you have a conflict you can run `git ls-files --unmerged` which will show the blobs involved, e.g.

```bash
$ git ls-files --unmerged
100644 580e1f54a104293b815bc3877ec479401638ce6d 1       main.c
100644 9e9a65b7a9298e178e34f161e3cd0054118ad91d 2       main.c
100644 ab6709455f9e2bad93c361c59f20f6d6eb3e2446 3       main.c
$
```

The content for these you can fetch with `git cat-file blob` and then use with a proper 3-way merge tool. More details, including descriptions of the numbers, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75466484/23118).

Or, much more conveniently you can use [my script](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3) that does all that automatically under the hood and launches KDiff3 with all the blobs:

[image: KDiff3 screenshot]

---

If you want to track down the exact commit where the blob is originating from that is not necessary an question [with just one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58472431/23118).